# reviewboard install error on Solaris

Tags: django, solaris

I'm trying to install reviewboard on Solaris 10, but I have this error message below and can not get rid of it. The environment is Solaris 10, python 2.4.

---

```
bash-3.2# easy_install ReviewBoard?-1.5.7   
Processing ReviewBoard?-1.5.7
Running setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /home/fujita/Downloads/ReviewBoard-1.5.7/egg-dist-tmp-C1FAsb
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'locale'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/*/_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'reviewboard/htdocs/media/uploaded/images'
ReviewBoard? 1.5.7 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing rb-site script to /usr/bin
Installing rbssh script to /usr/bin
Installed /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/ReviewBoard-1.5.7-py2.4.egg
Processing dependencies for ReviewBoard?==1.5.7
Searching for Django>=1.1.3
Reading  http://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/
No local packages or download links found for Django>=1.1.3
Best match: None
```

---

This error tells me that there should be Django installed on, I think that Django was already installed successfully.

---

```
bash-3.2# cd Django-1.3.5
bash-3.2# python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_scripts
running install_lib
running install_scripts
changing mode of /usr/bin/django-admin.py to 755
running install_data
bash-3.2# ls -lt /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/
```

### drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 19 Aug 19 18:03 django

Question is why during installing reviewboard it can't find Django which is already installed?
Does anyone have any idea what kind of situation I'm in and any comments would help.

Thank you very much.

TomoyaFujita.

Comment: There is no error message in what you posted.

Comment: - still not there ... Please update your question to include it !

Comment: the error message is "No local packages or download links found for Django>=1.1.3", and after that "Best match: None", and then installing stops. It seems that it can't find Django which is already installed, the django is installed /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django. Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Again, please edit your question to add the missing error message ! Nobody is going to read the comments to understand what your question is about.

Comment: thanks, it's been updated.